# Sub New() has multiple definitions with identical signatures

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, winforms

I was working in ASP.Net web forms application (website not web application) on Win 7 and everything was fine.

I had to transfer my solution to another machine also win 7, once I did that everything became NOT OK.

when I build my solution I got tons of building errors in files existing in

`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

most of these errors such

`Protected Sub New(info As System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, context As System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext) has multiple definitions with identical signatures.`

and

`Public Sub New()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.`

I googled it and tried all solution stated in all sites. clearing my solution and rebuild it,
clearing `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder, clearing `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp` and also manually deleted `.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs` exists in Temp folder

even I created new solution with different name but of course I imported files from old solution.

Nothing work for me, I don't know what is the problem exactly and why it happen and how can I solve it and back my solution to live?

Comment: You need to remove one or more of the New() declarations thats why...

Comment: my code does not contain many `New()` and these 'New()' exists in temp files generated by .Net

Comment: How exactly you moved solution to another machine?

Comment: @Fabio just zipped it and send it using `BigAnt` massanger

Comment: References in the project: do you using `CopyLocal = true or false`?

Comment: @Fabio `CopyLocal = true` for all references  :(

Comment: Usually when you use Visual Studio to generate some code for you (for data or whatever) it does them as `Partial Class ...` so you can create another partial class and add your own code to the same class without loosing your changes when the tool regenerates it's code. Long story. Anyway, since this is a web site, all files in the folder are part of the project. If you accidently copy the same file twice, it is automatically added and your partial class with the same methods and properties (like NEW) now have multiple definitions. Look for copies of the same classes.

Comment: @Steve, thanks.
I found two dataset files with different name but .Net generate the same class name for both, I removed one file and my project back to live again, Add your comment as answer to be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you use Visual Studio to generate some code for you (for data or whatever) it does them as `Partial Class ...` so you can create another partial class and add your own code to the same class without loosing your changes when the tool regenerates it's code. Long story.

Anyway, since this is a web site, all files in the folder are part of the project. If you accidently copy the same file twice, it is automatically added and your partial class with the same methods and properties (like NEW) now have multiple definitions.

Look for copies of the same classes.